# Why 'JPanel' isn't working?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

The `panel.add()` is *red* for some mysterious reason. The `panel` is initialized right above!

```
public class ShowImage {

    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("D:/java.jpg");
    JLabel label = new JLabel("sdasd", image, JLabel.CENTER);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);  
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot invoke a method directly in class. I believe you want to invoke that in  constructor.

```
public class ShowImage {
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("D:/java.jpg");
    JLabel label = new JLabel("sdasd", image, JLabel.CENTER);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    public ShowImage (){
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put all this code(or atleast the `panel.add` statement) inside a method. You can't just let that piece of code hang around in the class anywhere. Calling a method just anywhere in the class is not allowed in Java.

You can probably put it in the constructor or some init method.

```
public class ShowImage {
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("D:/java.jpg");
    JLabel label = new JLabel("sdasd", image, JLabel.CENTER);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    public void someInitMethod() { // or even the constructor
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```